# Terminal command to show a summary of memory used, temperature, and GPU use in a single screen, in a simple way

Tags: command-line, temperature, sensors, lm-sensors

Is there a Terminal command to show a summary of memory used, temperature degrees, and GPU use in a single screen, in a simple way?

I want in terminal to give me information in a summary fashion of Memory used (not swap etc.), GPU Use (as a percentage), and temperature degrees - how hot is getting CPU?

Right now, I must use three different terminal commands:

```
watch free -m    # For Memory use
watch sensors    # For Temperature
watch ndivia-smi # For GPU use
```

Is there a way to display such information in a single screen?
These commands produce a lot of information that someone may not need it rightaway.

The first line may show the memory use.
The second line may show GPU use.
The third line may display Temperatures.

I want from `free -m` "available". I want from `nvidia-smi` "Volatile GPU-Util" and from `sensors` all the temperatures in percentage without showing their limits (from that to that), for example

```
Available memory    5500000          

Volatile GPU-Util  20% 

CPUtemp1           40oC
Fantemp1           41oC
FanTemp2           42oC
etc...
```

Is that possible?

Sample outputs:

`free -m` output

```
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7815        1938        3548         188        2328        5391
Swap:          2047          57        1990
```

`nvidia-smi` output

```
$ nvidia-smi
Fri Jul 31 18:35:45 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.138                Driver Version: 390.138                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GT 1030     Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 32%   44C    P8    N/A /  30W |    220MiB /  1998MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
    |  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
    |=============================================================================|
    |    0      1770      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            82MiB |
    |    0      8182      G   /usr/bin/krunner                               6MiB |
    |    0      8184      G   /usr/bin/plasmashell                          55MiB |
    |    0     26370      G   ...AAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAA= --shared-files    74MiB |
    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

`sensors` output

```
$ sensors
it8620-isa-0a30
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:          +0.01 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)  ALARM
in1:          +2.05 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in2:          +2.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in3:          +2.02 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in4:          +0.01 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in5:          +1.74 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in6:          +1.50 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
3VSB:         +3.38 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +6.12 V)
Vbat:         +3.05 V  
fan1:        2986 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
temp1:        +47.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp2:       -128.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = disabled
temp3:        +35.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = Intel PECI
temp4:        +45.0°C  
temp5:        +42.0°C  
temp6:        +45.0°C  
intrusion0:  ALARM

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +97.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +97.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +45.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +92.0°C)
Core 0:        +43.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +92.0°C)
Core 1:        +44.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +92.0°C)
Core 2:        +42.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +92.0°C)
Core 3:        +40.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +92.0°C)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily extract the specific parts of interest from the long outputs by using various command-line utilities, e.g. `awk`.

You're interested in showing only the '*available*' memory from the output of `free -m`. Note that this number appears as the 7th string in the 2nd line of the output of `free -m`. So you can use the following command to extract this number

```
free -m | awk '{if (NR == 2) {print $7}}'
```

To "`watch`" the output, you can use the following

```
watch 'free -m | awk '\''{if (NR == 2) {print $7}}'\'
```

Similarly, it seems you want to extract the 2nd string from the 9th line from the output of the `nvidia-smi` command (`32%` as per the output you added to the question). So you can extract this value by the following command

```
nvidia-smi | awk '{if (NR == 9) {print $2}}'
```

and `watch` it using

```
watch 'nvidia-smi | awk '\''{if (NR == 9) {print $2}}'\'
```

From the output of `sensors` I believe you're trying to extract the 2nd string from line numbers 15 to 20 (which report `temp1` to `temp6`). So you can use

```
sensors | awk '{if (NR>=15&&NR<=20) {print $2}}'
```

and to `watch`

```
watch 'sensors | awk '\''{if (NR>=15&&NR<=20) {print $2}}'\'
```

To `watch` all three at the same time, you can use the following command

```
watch 'free -m | awk '\''{if (NR == 2) {print $7}}'\''; nvidia-smi | awk '\''{if (NR == 9) {print $2}}'\''; sensors | awk '\''{if (NR>=15&&NR<=20) {print $2}}'\'
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I had no idea for the awk command! Thanks, It worked. :) It is the 13th string for nvidia-smi :)

Comment: I feel you should also consider using `conky`, it's designed for this kind of specific tasks.

Comment: Can you post an example on Conky?

Comment: Conky has a slightly steep learning curve, you can start with any tutorial. It provides [many variables](http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html) to monitor your system and also supports monitoring the outputs from your own command or script with variables like `exec`, `execi` etc.